# Docker swarm doesn't build from Dockerfile correctly

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-swarm, docker-registry

Im using docker swarm with Docker version 19.03.3  engine.

I have a problem with psql build, it seems like Dockerfile does run correctly and i do push the new service to registry, but when container is up i discover that all COPY files are missing and psql extension "Postgis" that i install on Dockerfile is not installed.

I dont see any errors and that is why i dont know what is the issue.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y postgis
COPY cluster/ /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

swarm yml file:

```
        db:
                build: docker-compose.d/postgres
                image: 127.0.0.1:5000/postgres
                restart: 'always'
                environment:
                        - PG_MAX_WAL_SENDERS=8
                        - PG_WAL_KEEP_SEGMENTS=8
                        - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
                        - POSTGRES_USER=USER
                        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
                volumes:
                        - /db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
                deploy:
                 placement:
                   constraints:
                       - node.role==manager
```

steps:

```
docker service create --name=registry --publish published=5000,target=5000 registry
qhetvgzqj0f8g1t4nxxx76cqz
overall progress: 1 out of 1 tasks
1/1: running
verify: Service converged


docker-compose build --no-cache db #if i dont use --no-cache it doesnt rebuild service

Successfully built f6413978c21c
Successfully tagged 127.0.0.1:5000/postgres:latest

docker-compose push db
Pushing db (127.0.0.1:5000/postgres:latest)...
The push refers to repository [127.0.0.1:5000/postgres]
latest: digest: sha256:dccccdbdfxxxxxxxcb1e5b3a8a size: 3877

docker stack deploy base --compose-file docker-compose.swarm.yml
```

I see service is build :

```
docker service ls
lobelr1vzj8l        base_db                replicated          1/1                 127.0.0.1:5000/postgres:latest
```

container logs :

```
docker service ps --no-trunc base_db

ltujcwnx9m2v61hjuqtph6d7s   base_db.1           127.0.0.1:5000/postgres:latest@sha256:dccccdbdfafeb505b7ab349b21f4a580857c3cd51965cd36f81269cb1e5b3a8a   swarm-manager       Ready               Ready 4 seconds ago


docker service logs base_db
    psql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/postgres.sql:1: ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
```

Problem is The container doesn't really build with this command in Dockerfile
"RUN apt-get install -y postgis"

If i go to the container and run commands manually it works and also shows like extension was never installed before.

Why is that?
Thanks.

Comment: Why not just use [this docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/kartoza/postgis/) And change your FROM cmd to ```FROM kartoza/postgis```?

Comment: Because its PostgreSQL 9.6 and in prod we use PostgreSQL 11.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was changing in "docker-compose.swarm.yml" the service db image:

From :

```
 image: 127.0.0.1:5000/postgres
```

To:

```
 image: 127.0.0.1:5000/postgres:latest
```

I did all these checks first, to make sure my image has been registered to my local registry:

```
curl localhost:5000/v2/_catalog
{"repositories":["postgres"]}

localhost:5000/v2/postgres/tags/list
{"name":"postgres","tags":["latest"]}

curl localhost:5000/v2/postgres/manifests/latest

{
   "schemaVersion": 1,
   "name": "postgres",
   "tag": "latest",
   "architecture": "amd64",
   "fsLayers": [
      {
         "blobSum": "sha256:a3ed95caeb02ffe68cdd9fd8440668xxxx0e8a7c22955b46d4"...
```

And so i figured that it might be pushed as latest, and so does the image in Dockerfile should be.

## EDIT:

Another workaround i used is changing in dockerfile

```
FROM postgres
```

to

```
FROM postgres:11.5
```

and then in yml file :

```
image: 127.0.0.1:5000/postgres:11.5
```

For some reason the latest did issues for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you gave the `-y` cmd in the wrong place. I just built this image and it built successfully. If you want a specific version of postgres specify it instead of `latest` [check here](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/postgresql/)

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM postgres:latest
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install postgis -y
```

#### Output

```
docker image ls
REPOSITORY                       TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
postgis                          latest              eef15fa83f2f        2 minutes ago       645MB
```

Comment: If i run image as regular docker run it works.
my issue here is docker swarm + registry + Dockerfile something there doesn't work..
I also change the -y , same result.